# New iBus in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, ibus

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to type using the Japanese Anthy method in this new iBus on Ubuntu 13.10, since iBus is the default input method it's been changed since the last release. Is it even possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems all the settings has been moved to the regional settings screen. I use gnome shell, and you can find everything under Region & Language / Input Sources settings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a procedure to get Japanese input working using Japanese Anthy/IBus in Ubuntu 13.10.

http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2013/10/20/japanese-input-on-ubuntu-linux-13-10-saucy-salamander/

Instead of adding Anthy via the Input Method screen like in previous Ubuntus, you do it now from the language icon in the top panel.

Answer (score -1):

u haven't install ibus on ubuntu 13.10.it supply langue support already.when u want to active your languague which ubuntu not have yet....u can go go to langue support ->install/remove  languagues... tick on your languages u want to install.apply..it work for me with vietnamese unikey(default vietnamese telex)
Regards..